# Rotate transform not working in a media query

Tags: html, css, css-animations, vendor-prefix

I have a rotate animation that I am symbolizing that something is loading. This works great (except it doesn't rotate continuously, it kind of stops some when it has went around 360 degrees), but on some phones (I have an android note 4) it doesn't spin at all. Then on others (iphones) my circle actually rotates like it is swinging or it is fixed at one corner of the circle and it spins from that axis.

I have webkits in my code and I have the img set to this:

```
#spinning-circle img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Why would my image be doing these things. I can give the web url to see this live if you want to see it in a mobile setting.

```css
#spinning-circle-container {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  background: red;
  padding: 140px 0 0 10%;
}

#spinning-circle {
  animation-name: spinning-circle;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#spinning-circle img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinning-circle {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#spinning-circle-title {
  padding-top: 35px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 2.8em;
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  #spinning-circle-container {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 40px 0 0 6%;
  }
  #spinning-circle {
    animation-name: spinning-circle;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  #spinning-circle img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes spinning-circle {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  #spinning-circle-title {
    padding-top: 35px;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="spinning-circle-container">
  <div id="spinning-circle">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/spinning-circle.png">
  </div>
  <div id="spinning-circle-title">LOADING...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to use prefixed `-webkit-transform` in prefixed `@webkit-keyframes` and not-prefixed `transform` in not-prefixed `@keyframes`. And also you need to add prefixed `-webkit-animation`.
2. If you want animation doesn't stop at the end, you could use `animation-timing-function: linear`, but then animation'll have a constant speed.
3. You don't need to duplicate `@keyframes` and other properties inside `@media screen {}`.

```css
#spinning-circle-container {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    background: red;
    padding: 140px 0 0 10%;
}

#spinning-circle {
    -webkit-animation: spinning-circle linear 2s infinite;
    animation: spinning-circle linear 2s infinite;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#spinning-circle img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#spinning-circle-title {
    padding-top: 35px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 2.8em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    #spinning-circle-container {
        width: 80%;
        padding: 40px 0 0 6%;
    }

    #spinning-circle {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    #spinning-circle-title {
        color: blue;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinning-circle {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spinning-circle {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="spinning-circle-container">
    <div id="spinning-circle">
        <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/spinning-circle.png">
    </div>
    <div id="spinning-circle-title">LOADING...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the animation definition doesn't need to be inside the media query. (You only need to add the `animation-name: spinning-circle` and other rules within the media query).

Comment: @ingridly in this case I don't need, it's a duplicated string.

Comment: Sorry, what don't you need? (I wasn't suggesting a change to your answer, I was just clarifying to the OP what that was correct).

Comment: This works on the chrome browser on my phone, but still not my naitive android browser.  Also in Chrome (on my phone), the circle is still spinning like it is fixed on the top left corner.

Comment: @ingridly you said: "You only need to add the `animation-name: spinning-circle` and other rules within the media query)". I don't need to duplicate this property inside media query in this case, because the same animation works in both cases.

Comment: @Paul sorry, I haven't got an Android device to test it, but I tried in Genymotion emulator on some virtual devices, and I saw only `<img>` didn't load sometimes, but the animation worked. Does `<img>` load on your device? What're your phone model and Android version?

Comment: I have a Samsung note4. I forget the os name. It was the one that came with the phone.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `animation-timing-function: linear;` in your animation definition.
Here you have a code working https://jsfiddle.net/xhurpqLd/

-- EDIT --

You also have

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinning-circle {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) ;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) ;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) ;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) ;
    }
}
```

You only define the transform for webkit. Change to

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinning-circle {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) ;
        transform: rotate(0deg) ;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) ;
        transform: rotate(360deg) ;
    }
}
```

Here you have the updated code https://jsfiddle.net/xhurpqLd/3/. It works on my Android.

You can also add `-ms-transform` for IE support.

Comment: Thanks that helped making it work more smoothly, but it still doesn't work in my 640 viewport on my android phone.

Comment: Still nothing. I noticed that a little bit ago and tried removing the keyframe from the media query entirely, just so it picked up the code from the main css, but tha tdidn't help and this solution doesn't help either, unfortunately. The site it is on is.. http://optimumwebdesigns.com/test_index .. you will see it in the green section.

Comment: @DavidRosa added in the non-webkit property for the transform, but you'll still need the non-webkit version of the keyframe definition itself. `@keyframes spinning-cricle { `

Comment: @ingridly What do you mean?

Comment: Check out the `@keyframes` declaration here: https://jsfiddle.net/ingridly/xhurpqLd/4/

Comment: You need both the one with the `webkit` and the one without it.

Answer (score 0):

Lines 731-733 and 1391-1393 of `main-style.css` appear to be causing the *swinging* problem.

```
*::after, *::before {
    content: '';
}
```

should be

```
*::after, *::before {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
```

assuming you're trying to use [this](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) clearfix method